# Как конвертировать картинку в массив пикселей rgb

Tags: c++

Хочу конвертировать изображение в массив пикселей для дальнейшей обработки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Совсем простой вариант: [stb_image](https://github.com/nothings/stb).

Скачать, добавить в пути поиска инклудов.

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
```

```
int w = 0, h = 0;
unsigned char *data = stbi_load("путь", &w, &h, nullptr, 3); // если написать 4 - загрузит с прозрачностью
if (!data)
    ошибка

// Здесь `data` - массив размера w*h*3

stbi_image_free(data);
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста объяснить как добавить в поиски инклудов ?

Comment: И как отсюда брать rgb, если это char ?

Comment: @AndrewwSS `data[3*(x+w*y)+i]`, где `x`, `y` - координаты пикселя, `i` - канал: 0=R,1=G,2=B.

Comment: @AndrewwSS В настройках проекта поищите. Под рукой студии нет.

Comment: Exception thrown: read access violation. Часть считывает, а потом выдает ошибку @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @AndrewwSS Код покажите. И скажите на какой строчке ошибка.

Comment: У меня снова ошибки линковки, вечером все работал, а сейчас снова unresolved symbol stbi_load refrenced in function main. И такое же для второй функции. Я вписал папку к этому .h файлу в Additional Include Directories.

Comment: @AndrewwSS Ну значит сломали что-то. Например макрос убрали.

Comment: Вы зрите в корень. Именно макрос куда-то убрался. Вот мой код 
` for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
    cout << "(" << (int)data[3 * (i + w * j) + 0] << " " << (int)data[3 * (i + w * j) + 1] << " " << (int)data[3 * (i + w * j) + 2] << ")";
   }
  }`
вылетает на i = 0, j = 211, при этом w=261, h = 193

Comment: тут я просто хотел вывести всю матрицу по пикселям в rgb

Comment: @AndrewwSS Перепутали X и Y.

Comment: Благодарю, може пожалуйста дать наводку где можно почитать про этот способ записи в чаре и последуйщей, так скажем, дешифровке?

Comment: @AndrewwSS Не знаю, и мне кажется, что достаточно нарисовать это на бумажке, и все станет понятно. Точно так же устроены многомерные массивы. Допустим, размер картинки 4x2 пикселя. Нарисуйте ряд из 4*2*3 клеточек, в каждой подпишите координаты пикселя и букву r/g/b, и глазами найдите закономерность.

Comment: Спасибо я уже понял, тут получается в массив все по порядку записано r g b и дальше для следующего так же само